# Handing complex validation scenarios in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, validation

I'm been working on a `GetRuleViolations()` method for my `User` class, but I'm getting a little hung up on on something:

**What happens when different actions require different business rules?**

My `User` table has the following columns: `Id`, `UserRoleId`, `Username`, and `Password`. Several actions involving `User` are possible (create new user, edit user, set/reset password, and log in), and the business rules for each are not always the same.

For example, when users log in, they are required to enter a password, but when admins create a new user, entering a password is not even an option. And in the case of setting/resetting a password, the password needs to be entered *twice*, and the two values need to be an exact match. What is the best way to handle this complexity? Is there some kind of design pattern to allow the right `GetRulesViolations()` method to be selected for the right circumstance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm finding that a "service layer" to handle validation makes a lot of sense.

I found this tutorial very helpful:
http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-38-cs.aspx

Also, it looks as though some nice enhancements to validation are in the works for MVC 2.0 (see http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx). Using a `UserService` or `UserValidator` should allow the 2.0 features to be folded in without having to change class design too significantly.

Answer (score 0):

As to #1, the business rules won't exist in your database, they'll exist in the application, whether in a domain layer, separate business layer, etc... or right in your controllers, depending on your approach.

You'll present a different screen, or view, to a logged-in admin who is creating a user than you will present to an unauthenticated user who is creating an account, right? The HTTP-POST from that view is going to correspond to a different action, which will either handle the logic directly, or delegate to the appropriate object(s). One method will check the provided password and either create a record for the user or redirect the user to some sort of failure page ("passwords don't match" or "username already taken", for example). The other method will create a new user in the database, no questions asked.

Different views posting to different actions, corresponding to different methods, each of which handles a single, specific job/scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think my first question may have been a little unclear. I already have different views (e.g., User/LogIn, User/Create, User/Edit, User/EditPassword, etc.). What I need is a validation system that selects the right `GetRuleViolations()` method for the right action/view. I'm looking for advice on how to design my classes, etc. to do this.